# How to speed up precharging of the DC link capacitor of the three-phase inverter?

Tags: capacitor, power-electronics, control, charging, pid-controller

Let's say I have a three-phase inverter with a DC link capacitor of substantial capacity.

I would like to charge the DC link capacitor to a DC voltage. One possibility is to use a resistor which is temporarily connected in series with the capacitor. This resistor limits the inrush current and the capacitor will be charged in time t = 3·R·C s.

Let's say I would like to to speed up the charging process. One idea which I have is to use a control loop of the charging current and a transistor in
the actuator role. The transistor will be switched with a duty cycle which is the output of the current control loop. The idea is depicted here:

[image]

My problem is that I am not sure whether this approach is common. I have found only the variant with the resistor, so I have doubts whether I haven't
omitted anything important.

Can you tell me if the proposed idea with the current control loop is used in practice?

Comment: You don't say what the other constraints are in your scenario. Is there a time limit for precharging the DC bus? Is there a max power you can take to do it? Is there a cost (or dissipation) limit on the extra precharge components?  Is there a complexity limit? Using a series R guarrantees 50% of input power will be wasted. Using a SMPS for precharge can approach 100 % efficiency (so faster precharge for given input power). Normally precharge can be handled as a short duration higher pulse loading for your input circuit protection.

Comment: Ideally, a soft start buck regulator (aka efficient constant current source) looks best for your solution but, like Neil said, more detail is needed.

Comment: @Neil_UK thank you for your reaction. My question has only theoretical nature. I am only curious whether the proposed idea is used in practice or not.

Comment: The proposed 'solution' of PWMing a resistor doesn't seem to have any advantages. The resistor will heat to essentially the same temperature as it dissipates 50% of the energy in the DC link caps, however fast they charge (assuming < 10 s or so for adiabatic conditions). I doubt it's used anywhere for that reason. The practical solutions are a) no precharge, the fuse and diodes just handle the big initial pulse of current, b) simple resistor for slow precharge and c) SMPS for fast precharge. When you have a specification, you choose whether to afford the complexity and cost to meet it.

Comment: As @Andyaka said I've seen a buck regulator used for this purpose.  The regulator is current limited and runs in constant-current mode while precharging, then it's disabled once the precharge is complete.

Comment: Your circuit is not far away from a buck converter. Replace the resistor by an inductor, add a reverse diode to GND and there you are with good efficiency.